# I am not getting updated values for strings, Values are being assigned in onResponce() method of Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

//Code for Button that sets and gets values of Strings that are declared in Class level `private String hostApptSlots1, HApStrtT1,HAptAvgT1;`

```
getProfDetails(profname);
    Toast.makeText(Fix_Appointment.this,getHApStrtT1()+getHostApptSlots1()+getHAptAvg1(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

//Code for **getProfDetails** **apiService.ProfDetails** is using another Thread than **#Main_Thread**

```
    public void getProfDetails(String Pusrname){

            apiService.ProfDetails(Pusrname).enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
            @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) 
    {

                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(response.body().toString());
                    JSONObject  jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                   //Getting Values from JSONARRAY
                    hostApptStartTime=jsonObject2.getString("HP_StartTime"); 
                    hostApptAvgTime=jsonObject2.getString("HP_AvgTime");
                    hostApptSlots=jsonObject2.getString("HP_Slots");

                    //Setter Method used for Strings
                    setHostApptSlots1( hostApptSlots);
                    setHApStrtT1(hostApptStartTime);
                    setHAptAvgT1(hostApptAvgTime);
//Values are being set correctly i have checked this 


    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonArray> call, Throwable throwable) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I think two threads are executing concurrently Main Thread accessing value executes before than Back Thread which is setting values. If i pressed button two times it access values Exactly as initialized.

Comment: I think you should Parse it by POJO instead so you can be more efficient in handling Exceptions